# Prints incorrect statement - doesnt account for condition

Tags: python

this program keeps printing the first if statement no matter what condition is met

```
def elements():
  element = input("Enter an element of choice > ")
  if element.lower() ==='li' or 'lithium':
    print("Element: Lithium\nAtomic weight: 6.94\nGroup: Alkali metals(1)")
  elif element.lower() == 'h' or 'hydrogen':
    print("Element: Hydrogen\nAtomic weight:1.007\nGroup: Alkali metals(1)")
  elif element == 'he' or 'helium':
    print("Element: Helium\nAtomic weight:4.002\nGroup: Noble Gases(0)")
    
elements()
```

Output:

```
Enter an element of choice > h
Element: Lithium
Atomic weight: 6.94
Group: Alkali metals(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect:

```
if element.lower() == 'li' or 'lithium':
```

It is logically equivalent to:

```
if 'lithium' or (element.lower() == 'li'):
```

That is, 'lithium' always evaluates as `true` since you're not comparing it to anything, so having it as an `or` statement will always cause this if to be true.

You want

```
if element.lower() == 'li' or element.lower() == 'lithium':
```

Or

```
if element.lower() in ['li', 'lithium']
```

Comment: You have 19k rep, you should know how to close vote.